# Event constants for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, constants, dom-events, mouseevent

In Javascript I have code like:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownHandler);
```

and occasionally I might fat finger something like:

```
document.addEventListener("mouzedown", mouseDownHandler);
```

And Javascript won't recognize that I'm a moron and I'll be confused why my handler isn't working.

`Actionscript3` specifies event constants like so:

```
MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN // equiv to the String "mouseDown"
```

If I fat-finger a `variable` or `constant` then JS gets mad at me and I can solve the problem real quick. Does JavaScript have anything similar to to this or do I need to make my own JS pseudo-constants for event types?

Comment: Haha, yeah. In static languages, you get a compiler error. In dynamic languages, strings are about as safe as variables. (Not quite though.)

Comment: I've personally never come across something like this, and a few minutes via Google hasn't provided me anything. I did however learn that JavaScript has a `const` keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2C_Variables%2C_and_Literals#Constants

Comment: @Diodeus JavaScript would complain about an undefined variable though; so typing it incorrectly would give you the desired result.

Comment: @peterp If you ask for `MouseEvent.anythingGoesHere` JavaScript will _not_ complain; it will silently return `undefined`, which is accepted as a valid event name (at least on Chrome). This would only be valid if these were spammed as global variables.

Comment: `mouseDown` is an event generated by a browser or other container that happens to be running a javascript interpreter... it means nothing to javascript. You can invent, fire, and handle your own events with any names you want, so a fixed predefined set is out. It would then be up to the environment (the browser) to pre-define some const strings for you to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in feature to do this for you.

You could create your own list of events:

```
var EventNames = {
  MOUSE_DOWN : "mousedown",
  MOUSE_UP   : "mouseup",
  CLICK      : "click",
  // etc
};
```

But that doesn't protect you from typos because then `EventNames.MOUZE_DOWN` will just give you `undefined` (which will likely be accepted by `addEventListener()` but - obviously - not do what you want).

You could create a series of individual global variables and then the browser should give an error if you make a typo on the "constant" name (and your IDE or lint product may detect typos for you):

```
var Event_MOUSE_DOWN = "mousedown",
    Event_MOUSE_UP   = "mouseup",
    // etc
```

But of course members of the "globals are evil" brigade are already starting to froth at the mouth just from having read the above. You could do the above without globals by wrapping all of your code (including those "constants") in one big immediately-executed anonymous function, or you could instead do something like this:

```
// YNH: "Your Namespace Here" (insert your own namespacing
//                             code as desired)
var YNH_Events = {
   validEvents : ["mouseup","mousedown","click","etc"],

   bindEvent = function(element, eventType, handler, isCustomEvent) {
      if (!isCustomEvent && -1 === this.validEvents.indexOf(eventType))
         throw "Invalid event type requested: " + eventType;

      if (element.addEventListener)
         element.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
      else if (element.attachEvent)
         element.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler);
      else
         element["on" + eventType] = handler;
   }
}

YNH_Events.bindEvent(someElement, "mousedown", function() { });         // OK
YNH_Events.bindEvent(someElement, "customevent", function() { }, true); // OK
YNH_Events.bindEvent(someElement, "mouzedown", function() { });     // Error!
```

Of course, the usual caveat about using [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) applies, i.e., not supported in older browsers but you can shim it as described by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), blah, blah, blah.

Or you could do like jQuery and define your own `.mousedown()`, `.click()` etc methods and only attach events through those methods - you'll definitely get an error if you mistype the method name.

Comment: I've been doing constants inside an "immediately-executed anonymous function" for some time, but I may like your idea of defining my own function better. Perhaps even my own variation of "addEventListener" which checks for an `undefined` event_type. +1 for the idea!

Comment: When not using a library like jQuery I always define my own event binding function rather than using `addEventListener()` directly, just to encapsulate the cross-browser if/else nonsense shown above. Assuming you do the same it's no big deal to put a quick event-name validation check in too. (It's not a big overhead, but if you wanted to pull that bit out again just before deploying to a production environment, well, it's only one array declaration and an if test. I deliberately wrote the above to use an array of strings because it's much less fiddly than a bunch of constants.)

Answer (score 2):

There are no predefined constants/properties which can be used as to define an event for `addEventListener`.

*Stripped original answer below (and in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8438600/1)):*
The `Event` object defined the following constants. Using Firefox 8.0, and the following code:

- `alert(Object.keys(Event).map(function(name){return name + "\t" + Event[name]}).join('\n'))`

Comment: However, `Event.MOUSEDOWN` is not valid as a parameter to `addEventListener()`.

Comment: Under the impression that you were looking for any defined constants on the `Event` object, I posted this answer. **However, if you're looking for constants which contain anything such as `mousedown`, the answer is: No, there is not such a constant.** For more information on the `Event` object, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use jQuery? Big switch for a small problem, but jQuery has aliased functions for a lot of JS handlers, and if you spell a function name wrong you'll definitely get an error.

That is,

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownHandler); // right
$(document).mousedown(mouseDownHandler); // right

document.addEventListener("mouzedown", mouseDownHandler); // wrong, no error
$(document).mouzedown(mouseDownHandler); // wrong, throws error
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Ben. If you select your code and press the `{}` button it will be nicely formatted, or you can do it manually by intending four spaces. Or format code `inline` by quoting with the ` character.